# ERROR [object Object] in GET request with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic to build a mobile app that sends a GET request to a server, receives a list of items as a response and displays them on the page.

The code in home.ts is the following:

```
const url = <my_url>;
let day_id = <some_id>

this.response = this.httpClient.get(url);

this.response
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.items = res[day_id];
  });
```

I should get the response of the following structure:

```
{day_id: [{"time": ..., "name": ...}, {...}, {...}]}
```

Then I iterate over received items to display them, like this:

```
<ion-list>
<button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemTapped($event, item)">
  {{item.time}}
  <div class="item-note" item-end>
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
</button>
```

But unfortunately, when I run the app, it gives some `ERROR [object Object]`. It happens, as I can see, inside of `this.response.subscribe`.

I have no clue to what the issue can be related to. So any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean, you cannot see the  response at all? Or you can see the response in items, but html is not loaded correctly?

Comment: [object object] usually appears when the object is empty. are you sure that your GET response is working correctly?

Comment: @Minu, I can see what 'this.response' is right after 'this.response = this.httpClient.get(url);'. Inside 'subscribe' is where the error happens.

Comment: @Arya when I simply type the url I want to receive in my browser I get the result that I expected

Comment: @ValeriaS. what is the response you are getting when you browse the url directly in the browser

Comment: @NinjaJami like this: {"3": [{"time": "09.00", "name": "...", ...},{...}]}. Each item in the list has the same structure.

Comment: @ValeriaS. the issue is you are trying to iterate an object not an array. For example this { } would be treated as an object in javascript so you couldn't iterate . If you want to iterate it shouls be like this []

Comment: @ValeriaS. Can u share your full json in a sample stackblitz or copy paste full valid json in your question by directly browse in the browser

Comment: @ValeriaS. you can go to https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wfj2ih?file=data.json and copy paste the json data and click on the fork button and share the url to me if you need further help

Comment: @Minu are you printing to the console and getting that error? Are you using a `+` in there? If so, are you using a comma `,` like this ```console.log('response:::', res)```

Comment: @Flignats I think you tagged the wrong person :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the response you're going to get is of the format:

```
{day_id: [{"time": ..., "name": ...}, {...}, {...}], ...}
```

And you want a consolidated list of all the `{ time: ..., name: ..., ... }` Objects, you can make this small change in your `subscribe` block:

```
this.response
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    const finalArray = [];
    Object.keys(res).forEach(key => finalArray.push(...res[key]));
    this.items = finalArray;
});
```

`day_id` should be a string.

Comment: In the day_id variable I store a string from "0" to "6". So the object res doesn't have the property "day_id", it rather has a property like "2", "3", etc.

Comment: But your question states that the response you're expecting is of that format. I'd urge you to log `res` to the console the way I've done here and share it in your question so that the actual issue could be identified.

Comment: Well, I've already logged res to the console but it is not printed - instead, I get the ERROR [object Object].

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic) replicating your issue?

Comment: Now I deleted the `this.items = res[day_id];` line, and simply logging `res` inside of `subscribe` gives the same error

Comment: OK, I'll do that

Answer (score 0):

you needs quotes around `day_id` in your response like so

```
this.response
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.items = res['day_id'];
  });
```

It is trying to view `day_id` as a variable when it is actually an object property.